# Imputing missing values for "days ago" feature

Tags: missing-data, data-imputation

I have a dataset with features such as `last_visit_n_days_ago`, `last_purchase_n_days_ago`. These features are unavailable for many rows, which might have an important predictive value. The question is what to put in these cells if I want to use a learning algorithm that does not support missing values.
My options are:

- super large number (e.g. `1e38`) to
- the maximal number available for this database, plus some margin. What can be a good margin in this case
- something else

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the model you are going to use. If it is tree-based, a value outside the existing range will suffice. This will, however, not work for all models (e.g. linear regression)

Other approaches to consider:

- Drop the rows with missing values (if there aren't too many)
- Fill them with the mean/median/most_frequent value
- Fill them using another model like KNN ([sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.KNNImputer.html#sklearn.impute.KNNImputer) or [impyute](https://impyute.readthedocs.io/en/master/#)), or even more advanced model.